# How to read Chinese word embedding in plain text with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, word-embedding

I'm a new beginner of numpy. I want to use pretrained Chinese word embedding for RNN training. I want to read the embedding in plain text and convert them into .npy file. But I always got errors. I used python3.4, and numpy1.13.

The embedding are stored in plain text as the examples show, separated by space:

Chinese word1 0.001334 0.001473 -0.001277 -0.001093 ……

Chinese word2 0.000417 -0.000250 -0.000319 -0.001105 ……

When I use np.loadtxt:

```
with open('/home/public/wordembedding/bigdata/test.txt',encoding='utf-8') as fr:
    np.loadtxt(fr,dtype=str)
```

I got the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\uff0c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

If I try np.genfromtxt

```
with open('/home/public/wordembedding/bigdata/test.txt',encoding='utf-8') as fr:
        np.genfromtxt(fr,delimiter=',',dtype=str)
```

I got

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

I googled a lot, but still fail to solve the problems, I have wasted a lot time. Are there anyone can help me? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Tried. reading seems fine. Are you trying to print the data, maybe your console doesn't support UTF-8?

Comment: I wrote the code in sublime text3 and ran it on the server, but the errors always show on the screen. So I totally have no idea. Anyway, thank you all the same.